# How does file system access time compare between an android phone and a desktop pc?

Tags: android

how fast is it possible to access and manipulate persistent files on android? Is it e.g. faster or slower than to access/manipulate files on the hdd of a desktop PC?

I heard that SSDs are faster than HDDs and SSDs are similar to SD cards, so that is why file access on android could be faster. But on the other hand I also heard that SD card file transfer rates are considered to be quite low because you also have to get access to them, on a PC e.g. by using a card reader and I do not know how it is on android.

The background of my question is actually that I want to weight the pros and cons of whether it is ok to load and store my data persistently on the android file system between each step of data manipulation in my app or whether the costs are simply too high in performance.

Thank you for help!

Comment: what are your requirements, how many records are we talking about?, have you considered using a local database such as SQLite?. Android might be slower than a PC, but depending on the amount of data you have that might be still reasonable for your needs

Comment: actually we are talking about (two) camera images as data and a couple of image transformations. As I said there are some reasons to make them persistent after each step of the different manipulations but I wondered how much that would cost in performance doing this on a mobile device.